# How to disable edit mode of oracle apex interactive grid on double click?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracleapplications

I am using an interactive grid in oracle apex. When we double click the grid it goes into an edit mode. I want to get rid of this functionality because my grid is not editable this way.

Comment: Grid region -> Attributes -> Edit Enabled = No

Comment: I want the grid to be editable coz I have update actions coming from other places. I just dont want interactive grid to go into edit mode everytime someone double clicks on it.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand you. You want the grid editable, but you don't want the user to be able to put it in edit mode? What "other places" are you talking about?

Comment: For instance, I have popup where users can fill data which will update the rows. I dont want users to be able to update rows by going into the edit mode.

Comment: It's a bit of an edge case but fair enough. I don't know the answer off the top of my head but there might be a grid event you could hijack to do this.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want the user to be able to edit row content, change the column type under Report -> Columns -> Your column -> Type. For example try setting it to Display only so that the users cannot change the content.

Comment: Yes, that I can do. However, it does not stop interactive grid from going into edit mode on double click.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to replicate the same from a long time. Just found a workaround for this.

1. Create Dynamic Action on Interactive grid on event Double Click
2. Set Action = Execute JavaScript Code
3. Use following code in action

   ```js
   apex.region("emp").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").set("edit", false);
   ```

Make sure to replace `emp` with static ID which you should provide in IG region.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide Edit button from interactive grid by do the following steps :

1- Click the page name

2- in the page attributes search for Java Script

3- type the following java script code in Execute When Page Loads

```
$('[data-action="edit"]').hide();
```

4- Save and run your page

Answer (score 0):

To prevent going into edit mode, you can extend the existing grid widget's setEditMode public method:

```
(function($){
    var bodyElem = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    bodyElem.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
        if (event.target.nodeName === "SCRIPT")
        {
            // grid subwidget
            let srcAttr = event.target.getAttribute("src");
            if (srcAttr && srcAttr.includes('widget.grid'))
            {
                $.widget("apex.grid", $.apex.grid, {
                    setEditMode: function (editMode, select) {
                        if (editModeDisabled)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        return this._super(editMode, select);
                    }
                });                
            }
        }
    }, true); 
})(apex.jQuery);
```